# How do I subset columns in R based on the length of the column names?

Tags: r

I have a data table which has some columns with long, ~20 letter names such as `GTEX.12WSJ.1226.SM.5LU91`. I have other columns with shorter, truncated versions of those names, like `GTEX.12WSJ`. I need to extract the long-named columns into a separate table from the short named columns. I want both types of columns to exist on separate columns, and I want the original table to basically disappear, like `rm(dt)` or something.

How do I go about doing this? The closest I've come is `which(nchar(names(dt)) > 9)` which creates a vector of numbers going from 1 to the number of columns which fit this condition.

Comment: From that you can extract the dataset `i1 <- which(nchar(names(dt)) > 9); dt[i1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `split.default` and split the columns based on number of characters

```
list_df <- split.default(df, nchar(names(df)) > 9)
```

where individual dataframes can be extracted with `list_df[[1]]` and `list_df[[2]]`.

For example, on this dataset we divide the data into two sets. One with columns greater than 2 characters and another with less than equal to 2 characters.

```
df <- data.frame(abc = 1:5, ab = 1:5, a = 6:10, abcd = 11:15)
split.default(df, nchar(names(df)) > 2)

#$`FALSE`
#  ab  a
#1  1  6
#2  2  7
#3  3  8
#4  4  9
#5  5 10

#$`TRUE`
#  abc abcd
#1   1   11
#2   2   12
#3   3   13
#4   4   14
#5   5   15
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just subset the data using the logic OP created

```
i1 <- which(nchar(names(dt)) > 9)
dt[, i1, with = FALSE] # if it is a data.table
```

Or use `subset`

```
subset(dt, select = which(nchar(names(dt)) > 9))
```

---

Or using `select`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  select(names(dt)[nchar(names(dt))> 9])
```

#### data

```
dt <- data.table(GTEX.12WSJ.1226.SM.5LU91 = 1:5, GTEX.12WSJ = 6:10, ab = 11:15)
```